# Saving files to a specific Folder using codepen

Tags: javascript, codepen

I am making a program on codepen, and I figured out how to save a file, however, I was wondering if it was possible to save the files to a specific folder on a computer. Ive had a look around and not too sure if its possible to be done on a browser type set up such as codepen.

Thanks

Comment: I've only used CodePen for testing, a lot like JSFiddle or PHPFiddle, but it should be possible either with PHP (which would be easy), or perhaps with a library like **downloadify** as is noted in this answer since I believe JS alone does not have the appropriate permission (probably due to XSS) https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405233/8382028